# Express.js Mocha testing having issues connecting to test db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mocha.js

I am trying to get my test suite to run within my express.js app, but this is my first express.js app as well as my first time working with mocha and I am unsure how to set everything up.

Here is my test

```
should = require 'should'
assert = require 'assert'
expect = require 'expect'
request = require 'superagent'
mongoose = require 'mongoose'
config = require '../../config/config'


describe "POST", ->
  app = require('../../app')

  beforeEach (done)->
    mongoose.connect config.db, (err) ->
      if err
        console.log "Error! #{err}"

      done()

  describe '/users/:id/activities', ->
    it 'should return created document', (done) ->
      request(app).post('http://localhost:3000/users/1/activities').send(
        description: "hello world"
        tags: "foo, bar"
      ).set('Content-Type','application/json')
      .end (e, res) ->
        console.log(res.body.description)
        expect(res.body.description).should.equal('hello world')
        done()
```

A couple of issues I am having are... 1) In the test suite it can't connect to my test db (in my config file); 2) I am getting this error message when trying to `post`

```
1) POST /users/:id/activities should return created document:
     TypeError: Object #<Request> has no method 'post'
```

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to get everything running properly?

The error I am getting back from trying to connect to the MongoDB is `Error! Error: Trying to open unclosed connection.`

I am running the mocha suite by running this command

```
NODE_ENV=test mocha test/controllers/activities.test.coffee --compilers coffee:coffee-script/register -R spec
```

**Edit**

activities.coffee (routes)

```
express  = require 'express'
router = express.Router()
mongoose = require 'mongoose'
Activity  = mongoose.model 'Activity'

module.exports = (app) ->
  app.use '/', router

router.post '/users/:id/activities', (req, res, next) ->
  activity = Activity(
    user_id: req.params.id
    description: req.body.description,
    tags: req.body.tags
  )

  activity.save (err)->
    if not err
      res.json(activity)
    else
      res.json({ error: err })

router.get '/users/:id/activities/:activity_id', (req, res, next) ->
  Activity.findById req.params.activity_id, (err, activity) ->
    if not err
      res.json(activity)
    else
      res.json({ error: err })
```

app.js

```
require('coffee-script/register');

var express = require('express'),
  config = require('./config/config'),
  fs = require('fs'),
  mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect(config.db);
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', function () {
  throw new Error('unable to connect to database at ' + config.db);
});

var modelsPath = __dirname + '/app/models';
fs.readdirSync(modelsPath).forEach(function (file) {
  if (/\.coffee$/.test(file)) {
    require(modelsPath + '/' + file);
  }
});
var app = express();

require('./config/express')(app, config);

app.listen(config.port);

exports.app = app;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, once you have your superagent pointing to you app variable that holds you routes, middlewares and so on, there is no need to specify the url in the methods provided by superagent. You just need to provide the route, just like so:

```
request(app)
  .post('/users/123/activities')
  .end(function (err, response) {
  });
```

Second, use the `before` statement provided by mocha instead of `beforeEach`, the second one will try to connect to mongo on every unit test you have.

For the first error

```
request has no method 'post'
```

Make sure you have installed superagent and you can find it on your `node_modules` folder.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! Im going to give that a try

Comment: I was able to locate the `superagent` module in my application. Let me paste the Route I am trying to test

Comment: There it is, your are connecting to mongo from your spec code and also from your app.js that serve your routes. You don't need to connect to mongo in your test.

Comment: Ah, gotcha! Well the mongo error went away (naturally), but now I am getting `1) POST /users/:id/activities should return created document:
     Uncaught AssertionError: expected { actual: 'hello world' } to be 'hello world'` And if in my console.log of res.body.description, I can see hello world returned

Comment: your're trying to use all of the available assertion modules, this is a mistake, you just need to use one. More info at [mocha website](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/#assertions)  
  
`should = require 'should'`  
`assert = require 'assert'`  
`expect = require 'expect'`  
  
Choose one that you like most and do assertions based on they framework, mocha website has a link to all of them.

Comment: It's now working!!! Thank you so much for your help! One more question, is there a way to setup my suite to run with just using `mocha` vs having to use this `NODE_ENV="test" mocha test/controllers/activities.test.coffee --compilers coffee:coffee-script/register -R spec`